# C# Reading only specific lines without reading line by line

Tags: c#, large-files

I been googling for the last hour and can not find an answer to this.

I have a large text file (1GB) and I also have a file which has this all mapped so I know that on line x to line y it contains the data I am after.

My question is how do I take only the lines I am interested in without iterating through all the lines in the file?

The main reason I am interested in doing it this way is for performance reasons, I imagine it be quicker to take rows 503,432 to row 504,432 than cycle from row 1 to 504,432 to find these rows.

Any tips much appreciated

Comment: If you are looking for a specific row number, you need to read all rows to count them anyway. There is know way you can count the rows without reading the file.

Comment: You say you have the x,y lines to read, but if your lines are of different length this info is useless

Comment: Is each of your lines the same length - *in bytes*? If so, you can seek to the right place. Otherwise, you won't be able to.

Comment: hmm okay I had not thought of it like that. They wont be the same length in bytes. Okay looks like I will need to read through line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a specific row number, you need to read all rows to count them anyway. You can't count the rows without reading the file except if the lines are fixed length. You do not need to save the lines when you read them. Only save the linenumber you need, or handle them without keeping them in memory for later.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case of premature optimization.
I'm processing ~6GB files using [FileHelpers AsyncEngine](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/example_async.html) and 'reading of the file' part is not the slowest part of the process by any means.

How long does is take to read first 500k lines and do nothing? How much time are you going to save?

Comment: I think you are right, I am researching into large file vs small files for an application